# SQLite checking data and getting data from database table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am beginner. I just want to make a program that user will enter the data on my EditText then program will search this data from database. If it is found, it will get all data related to the data(which user entered) then they will be shown in my TextView. I writed some codes, but it didn't work. Please help me.

"bNum" is name of coloumn in my table.

This is some part of my code:

```
final EditText bnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                DataSearch((bnumber.getText()).toString());

            } finally {
                book.close();
            }

        }
    });

}

private static final String[] SELECT = { "bNum" };
protected void DataSearch(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = book.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query("btable", SELECT, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        if (c.toString() == s)
        ShowingData(c);

    }}
       private void ShowingData(Cursor c) {


    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Information\n");
    String pName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pName"));
    String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price"));
    String quantity = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("quantity"));
    builder.append(pName).append("Product Name:");
    builder.append(price).append("Price:");
    builder.append(quantity).append("Quantity:");

    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    result.setText(builder);

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can´t see Your database, and don´t know how your query method works. But for example, if You query the whole db with a cursor object that returns all values from every row, this should work:

```
    protected void DataSearch(String s) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = book.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor c = db.getAllDatas();
       c.moveToFirst();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
      if (c.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase(s))
      ShowingData(c);

   }}
```

getAllDatas() should be a method where You get all Datas from the database.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is done with `equals()` method

try replacing your

```
if (c.toString() == s)
```

with

```
if (c.toString().equals(s))
```

Comment: yes, you are right! Thank you. But it doesn't solve my question.

Comment: what problem/exception you are getting?

Comment: The data isn't shown in my TextView. So it means that my codes aren't working.

Comment: if capital letters are not important, maybe try c.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s));, because by opening the keyboard, in some cases the first letter is automatically a capital.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  Okey, i'll change it. But how about my DataSearch method? Is there any something wrong?

Comment: I think c.toString() is not the right way. Which Value do You want to get? To get a string from a column inside a database, c.getStrint(columnNumber) is the right way. You have to pass an integer with the number of the column where do you want to get the info. For example if the value is inside the first column, it is c.getString(0); And, before getting values by while (c.moveToNext()), call c.moveToFirst();

Comment: @Opiatefuchs My database table consist of 4 coloumns. These are "bNum","pName","price","quantity".I want to check the data in my EditText if exist or not exist in "bNum" coloumn of my database table. If exist, i want data that row of my database table(for example user enter "a". and it is in my bNum[3]. i want pName[3],price[3],quantity[3]).

Comment: I put an answer. This would be the best that is possible from the information above. If You don´t understand what I mean, it would be helpfull to see Your database class

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I thank you so much. "c.getString(columnNumber)" is working well for my code! You make it clear for me! I really thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help you....if this was the right way I would be thankful if You vote me :)